# How do we know if a table is managed table or external able?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In hive when I run `show tables;` I get the list of all the tables, how do I know which of these are managed tables and which are external tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to get details of specified table:

```
describe formatted <your_table>;
```

The output will contain a row describing `table type`:

> Table Type:           EXTERNAL_TABLE

or

> Table Type:           MANAGED_TABLE

Answer (score 1):

For a single table you can use `desc formatted` or `desc extended`

### Demo

```
create table mytable (i int);
create external table myexttable (i int);
```

#### desc formatted

```
hive> desc formatted mytable;
...
Location:               hdfs://horton/user/dmarkovitz/mytable
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
...
```

---

```
hive> desc formatted myexttable;

...
Location:               hdfs://horton/user/dmarkovitz/myexttable
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
...
```

#### desc extended

```
hive> desc extended mytable;
...
Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:mytable ... tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

---

```
hive> desc extended myexttable;
...
Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:myexttable ... tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)
```

For many/all tables, you can query the metastore (Hive metadata database).

### metastore

(In this demo the metastore is in mysql)

```
select  d.name          as database_name
       ,t.tbl_name
       ,t.tbl_type

from            metastore.DBS   as d

        join    metastore.TBLS  as t  

        on      t.DB_ID =
                d.DB_ID

where   d.name = 'dmarkovitz'
;
```

---

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+
| database_name |  tbl_name  |    tbl_type    |
+---------------+------------+----------------+
| dmarkovitz    | mytable    | MANAGED_TABLE  |
| dmarkovitz    | myexttable | EXTERNAL_TABLE |
+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

FYI, the EXTERNAL/MANAGED property is nothing but a flag (metadata level) and it can be changed using `ALTER TABLE` command

**hive**

```
alter table mytable set tblproperties ("EXTERNAL"="TRUE");
alter table myexttable set tblproperties ("EXTERNAL"="FALSE");
```

**metastore**

```
select  d.name          as database_name
       ,t.tbl_name
       ,t.tbl_type

from            metastore.DBS   as d

        join    metastore.TBLS  as t  

        on      t.DB_ID =
                d.DB_ID

where   d.name = 'dmarkovitz'
;
```

---

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+
| database_name |  tbl_name  |    tbl_type    |
+---------------+------------+----------------+
| dmarkovitz    | mytable    | EXTERNAL_TABLE |
| dmarkovitz    | myexttable | MANAGED_TABLE  |
+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You should add `show create table` as top 1 option -- the "EXTERNAL" keyword stands out on the 1st line of output, and you get the "LOCATION" info on its own line by the bottom. The most readable result by far.

Comment: I feel it is exactly the opposite way - for tables with many columns the description is being scrolled and you see only the bottom so "show create table" becomes not convenient,

Comment: *"scrolled"* -- you mean you work with Hive on a bloody *shell*?!? Ever tried a proper GUI like DBVisualizer?

Comment: Hive CLI and Beeline and Hue and Zeppelin and DbVisualizer :-). Depends  where and when.

Comment: Thank you, `desc formatted myexttable;` I somehow hadn't noticed the `TABLE TYPE` here.